# Digital selection for gain control not working instead showing 0

Tags: arduino-uno, digital, potentiometer

I am making a device which will have a button to measure the input and another button to reset and the inputs are variable analog values(0 to 5v) and output is a ratio of two analog input voltages. It also has a selection keys(two buttons) for four selections(like gain eg. if key1 == LOW key 2 == LOW then J = 1 and likewise)
but the problem is when i am multiplying j with it the output shows zero if I multiply numbers like 1,2,3etc without using j then the ratio value gets multiplied.

here is the code

```
    void setup() // put your setup code here, to run once:
    {
      Serial.begin(9600);
      pinMode( K1, INPUT );
      pinMode( K2, INPUT );
      pinMode( MeasureButton, INPUT );
      pinMode( ResetButton, INPUT );
      dsp.begin(20, 4);
      current = millis();
    }

    void loop() 
    { 

      while(current < wait)
      {
      Serial.println("INITIALIZING");
      delay(1000);
      current = millis();
      }
      Serial.println("                   ");
      delay(1000);
      Serial.println(" READY TO MEASURE ");
      delay(2000);
      while (digitalRead(MeasureButton) == LOW) 
      {
        if(K1 == LOW && K2 == LOW)
        {J = 1; // SOMETHING VALUE
        showMessage1();
        i = 0; 
        delay(1000);
        }if(K1 == LOW && K2 == HIGH)
        J= 2; // SOMETHING VALUE
        showMessage1();
        i = 0;
        delay(1000);
        if(K1 == HIGH && K2 == LOW )
        J= 3; // SOMETHING VALUE
        showMessage1();
        i = 0;
        delay(1000);
        if(K1 == HIGH && K2 == HIGH )
        J= 4; // SOMETHING VALUE
        showMessage1();
        i = 0;
        delay(1000);

      }
      while (digitalRead(ResetButton) == HIGH)
      {
      dsp.setCursor(1,0);
      dsp.print("                   ");
      Serial.println("                   ");
      delay(1000);
      dsp.setCursor(1,0);
      dsp.print("RESETED");
      Serial.println("RESETED");
      delay(1000);
      }
while (digitalRead(ResetButton) == LOW)
      {
      dsp.setCursor(1,0);
      dsp.print("                   ");
      Serial.println("                   ");
      delay(1000);
      dsp.setCursor(1,0);
      dsp.print("PRESS MEASURE");
      Serial.println("PRESS MEASURE");
      delay(1000);
      }
    }


    void showMessage1()
    {
       while(i<5)     
        {
        A = analogRead(A0);
        B = analogRead(A1);
        C = analogRead(A2);
        D = analogRead(A3);
        N = analogRead(A4);
        W1 = (A/N)*J;        // J is another variable whose value is dependent on K selection values
        W2 = (B/N)*J;        // J is another variable whose value is dependent on K selection values
        W3 = (C/N)*J;        // J is another variable whose value is dependent on K selection values
        W4 = (D/A)*J;        // J is another variable whose value is dependent on K selection values

        sumW1 = sumW1 + W1;
        sumW2 = sumW2 + W2;
        sumW3 = sumW3 + W3;
        sumW4 = sumW4 + W4;
        i++;
      }
        Serial.print("W1-");
        Serial.print(sumW1);
        Serial.print("W2-");
        Serial.println(sumW2);
        Serial.print("W3-");
        Serial.print(sumW2);
        Serial.print("W4-");
        Serial.println(sumW4);
        sumW1 = 0;
        sumW2 = 0;
        sumW3 = 0;
        sumW4 = 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  pinMode( K1, INPUT );
```

with

```
    if(K1 == LOW && K2 == LOW)
```

makes no sense. `K1` is a pin number. `LOW` is a macro for `0` (`HIGH` for `1`). You are comparing a static pin number against a static number.

If `K1` is not equal to 0, the inner part of that if statement can never be reached.

What you meant to do was "if the voltage at the pin K1 is low". For that you need to read out the current value of the pin and check it.

For that you must replace your `if(K1 == LOW)` type statements to `if( digitalRead(K1) == LOW)`.

I'd also like to mention that you must have a pull-up on your buttons for this "LOW"/"HIGH" logic to work. Either externally, or use `INPUT_PULLUP` instead of `INPUT` in `pinMode`.

Comment: you just saved me. :) I will correct that